# Bootstrap panel-footer with button pull-right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following HTML element with bootstrap:

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Save</button>
</div>
```

[image]

If you see there is a gray area (`panel-footer`):
[image]

The button uses `pull-right` class also that is `float:right`, but I would like the gray area that is actually the `panel-footer` `div` to fit within the button height.

This is the styles for `panel-footer`:

[image]

And this for the `pull-right`:

[image]

> Any clue?

UPDATE:

I added after the button:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

And seems that fixed the problem. Is that ok?

Comment: Hi can you please post a url for your actual code? I've created a codepen here with bootstrap and your html and it works fine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dONeqV

Answer (score 5):

### Original Answer (2017)

you can try this (Bootstrap 3)

```
<div class="panel-footer text-right">
   <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Save</button>
</div>
```

You just need to add **text-right** class to your panel-footer.

It works for me.

### Updates (2023-01-11)

#### Bootstrap 5

Use class `text-end` to make button realign to the right side.

```css
.panel-footer {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  border-top: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body class="p-4">
  <div class="panel-footer text-end">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Primary button</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Bootstrap 4 & 3

Use class `text-right` will make the alignment to the right.

```css
.panel-footer {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  border-top: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body class="p-4">
  <div class="panel-footer text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Primary button</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wondering why it's not working for me!

Comment: @FLICKER Hi buddy, I updated my answer with different version of bootstrap. Make sure that your class is matching the right version of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code you provided in a jsFiddle and got the same results. Even placing the button within the panel panel-default, still got the same results.

Here is a fix.

I created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/csr6eqg9/1/)

It includes two example one using your code with an override and one using a panel panel-default and panel-body with a css override.

hope that helps.

```css
.panel-footer {
  height: 50px !important;
}

#sep {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.panel-body {
  background: #f3f3f3 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="panel-footer">
  <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Save</button>
</div>
<div id="sep"></div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Save</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me.

```html
<div class="footer">
        <a href="#" id="btnSave" class="pull-right btn btn-primary">Save</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="panel-footer">
     <div class="form-group text-right">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can align your text right to move your button to the right but it will not work when you have an image acting as a button or something else in the footer that is not essentially text.

The right approach to use would be to add `clearfix` class in your `panel-footer` div. i.e.

Instead of this:

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</button>
</div>
```

You should use:

```
<div class="panel-footer clearfix">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</button>
</div>
```

Which, I think, is already addressed in the op's question but with a different placement of the element with `clearfix` class.

View it on [codepen](https://codepen.io/jamsshhayd/pen/zYMGPOR): https://codepen.io/jamsshhayd/pen/zYMGPOR

[image: Visually how it looks with the class applied]